# Alternative ways to say "by a vote of"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

I don't want to sound like I'm copying straight off of the article. I'm looking for another way to say "{Person} won the election by a vote of 533 to 1"

Comment: This question is far too broad as posed.

Comment: The tally was five hundred and thirty-three to one, {Person} wins.

Comment: "He won by 533 votes to 1"?

Comment: The election result was 533 votes to 1 in X's favour.

Answer (score 1):

"S/He had a landslide victory."

I think that 533 to 1 is certainly a landslide win.